# Codeigniter MySQL : Insert record not be same with user id

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

my controller

```
    // This will save all the updated values from the user.
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$data = array(
    'full_name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    'email'     => $this->input->post('email'),
    'address'   => $this->input->post('address'),
    'phone'     => $this->input->post('phone')
);      

    // And store user imformation in database.
$cust_id = $this->cart_model->update_customer($data, $id);

$order = array(
    'orderDate'     => date('Y-m-d'),
    'customerid'    => $cust_id
);
   // And store user order information in database.
$ord_id = $this->cart_model->insert_order($order);
```

my model

```
function update_customer($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('user', $data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    return (isset($id)) ? $id : FALSE;
}

    // Insert order date with customer id in "orders" table in database.
public function insert_order($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('order', $data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    return (isset($id)) ? $id : FALSE;
}
```

Table order : `id`, `orderDate`, `customerid`

Table user : `id`, `full_name`, `address`, `phone`

`customerid` in table order value `0` not the same as the user table, where is my mistake please corected
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function update_customer($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('user', $data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    return (isset($id)) ? $id : FALSE;
}
```

You cant use `$this->db->insert_id();` when updating a record so you should remove that line. 
You are already passing the id as function parameter so you could return that directly with

```
function update_customer($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('user', $data);
    return (isset($id)) ? $id : FALSE;
}
```